# How to provide screencasts to Facebook for app review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook app to publish content to my Facebook page automatically from a website. This app needs manage_pages & publish_pages permissions. Facebook asks apps to be reviewed in order to keep working. When I try to create a new submission for these permissions I have to provide screencasts of how my app uses these permissions. I can't provide such a video as this app gets called from PHP code. What should I do?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps

Comment: Dear @CBroe thank you for your help, but my problem is not how to upload the requested screencasts, but that I can't create a video of how my app works because all it does is posting content from my website, to my facebook page.

Comment: It specifically says on that page what you should do in regard to screencasts for this type of app. _“Provide a screencast that shows how data exchanged with our APIs ultimately gets used. For example, if your app pulls data from our APIs and feeds it into a CRM, show us how the CRM uses that data.”_ - so, show some articles from your website’s backend, and how those look on the Facebook page after your app published them there.

Comment: I have the same problem. I already requested for review twice but both got rejected. I followed the guidelines under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps however my app does not use any data from facebook but just creates new posts on a site a user manages. So I created a screencast that shows the C# code that creates the post but it got rejected too... can you give me some advice?

Comment: @rufer7 I did the review thing about 4 times and all got rejected because the person that reviewed it was trying to login as a normal user in my web app.Of course I had a clear guide on how to login as an admin (in video and by text). How difficult should it be to follow it? I believe they just did not pay attention.

Comment: @Huanonymous I submitted my request yesterday again for review with an animated powerpoint presentation that shows how the server interacts with the facebook API. Now it got accepted! There is no login button in my application and no test account that could be used as my application is an Azure function that runs on Azure and gets triggered every day at a specific time.

Comment: @rufer7 lol, maybe I should try that too. Good job

Answer (score 1):

You can find the demo by facebook here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps/sample-submission/